# Spinnaker CLI when spinnaker auth is SAML

Tags: command-line-interface, spinnaker

We have spinnaker setup to use SAML for authentication. We do not have a choice about this. It works fine, been using for a year.

There are some tasks we would like to execute using the spinnaker CLI "spin". However it seems that spin does not support SAML auth. We were wondering if we could setup a second auth method in spinnaker, say x509, then we could continue to use SAML for spinnaker UI and we could use x509 for spin client.

Is this possible? Is this the best way to setup our CLI?

Answer (score 2):

**X.509**

`spin` can be configured with X.509 to authenticate calls against Spinnaker. The configuration block looks like this:

```
auth:
  enabled: true
  x509:
    certPath: <cert file path>
    keyPath: <key file path>
```

or

```
auth:
  enabled: true
  x509:
    # Pipes for multi-line strings in yaml.
    # Cert and key contents are 64 encoded pem values.
    cert: |
    <cert>
    key: |
    <key>
```

Follow the [ssl](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/security/authentication/ssl/) and [x509](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/security/authentication/x509/) guides to generate the X.509 certificate and key files. Refer to the [example config](https://github.com/spinnaker/spin/blob/master/config/example.yaml) and the [README](https://github.com/spinnaker/spin/blob/master/README.md) for more information about X.509 in spin.

**OAuth2**

Client ID and Client Secret
`spin` can be configured with an OAuth2 client ID and secret to authenticate calls against Spinnaker. The configuration block looks like this:

```
auth:
  enabled: true
  oauth2:
    authUrl: # OAuth2 provider auth url
    tokenUrl: # OAuth2 provider token url
    clientId: # OAuth2 client id
    clientSecret: # OAuth2 client secret
    scopes: # Scopes requested for the token
    - scope1
    - scope2
```